# Objective-C variable that is accessible in other classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates, protocols

I have a NSString object called language and I want to access it from other classes what is the proper way? I tried following steps:

1) I created delegate method and send string via delegate

```
-(void)setLanguageForController:(NSString *)language {
     self.language = language;
}
```

Console showed this

> unrecognized selector sent to instance delegate

2) I created method getCurrentLanguage

```
static NSString *language;



+(NSString*)getCurrentLanguage {
   return language;
}
```

And access like this

> NSString *myLanguage = [[MyView alloc] getCurrentLanguage];

Answer (score 3):

you should declare `language` as a property in your class `.h` file.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* language;
```

When you want to set language:

- initalize your class instance: `yourObj`
- `call: yourObj.language = "whatever"`
  or `[yourObj setLanguage:"whatever"];`

  Each property declaration ends with a type specification and a name.
  For example:

> @property(copy) NSString *title;

This syntax is equivalent to declaring the following accessor methods:

```
- (NSString *)title;
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)newTitle;
```

read more about objective-C property [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/DeclaredProperty.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create your method like `setLanguageForController` and `getCurrentLanguage` to get and set the your variable like this if you want to access it from other class. You need to create a `property` in your `interface` file or .h file, it will be public and it provide its `getter` and `setter` method which you can access from any class by the `instance` variable of your class that contains your `property`.

You can declare your `property` in .h or class `interface` file like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* language;
```

To set it's value you can use.

```
obj.language = @"value"; or [obj setLanguage:@"value"];
```

To get its value. You need to use same `instance` variable like this

```
NSString *strLanguageValue = obj.language;
```